# Python SQLite You can only execute one statement at a time

Tags: python, sqlite

I get error when running this code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("Sqlite3 file path")
cursor = conn.cursor()

Name = "Test"
LastName = "Test"
Id = 2
Grade = 12

cursor.execute("""
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO Students (FirstName,LastName) VALUES(?,?);
    
    INSERT INTO StudentsYears (StudentId,YearId,Grade) VALUES((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID() from Students),?,?);
    
    END TRANSACTION;""" , (Name , LastName , Id , Grade))

conn.commit()
```

What is the problem?
.......................................

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using the wrong command to execute multiple SQL statements at once.
According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) *execute()* " will only execute a single SQL statement. If you try to execute more than one statement with it, it will raise a ProgrammingError. Use executescript() if you want to execute multiple SQL statements with one call. "

To fix your issue change your code to

```
cursor.executescript("""
    STATEMENTS
    ...
    """
```